# Playing the same sound at the same time? (swift, spritekit)

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Im trying to play a pop sound whenever a ball is touched but if the ball is touched again, before the pop sound ends, the sound will not play. I want the pop sound to cut out and start playing again if the ball is touched over and over again. The code i have now is below...

```
      let popSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("pop",withExtension: "wav")
      let Pop = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: popSound, error: nil)

 ////this is in the touches begin function/////

      if touchedNode==ball{
        Pop.play()
    }
 //////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845906/avaudioplayer-stop-a-sound-and-play-it-from-the-beginning

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the help of this post. [AVAudioPlayer stop a sound and play it from the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845906/avaudioplayer-stop-a-sound-and-play-it-from-the-beginning)
I needed to set the Pop.currentTime to = 0

```
 if touchedNode==ball{
 Pop.currentTime=0
 Pop.play()
 }
```